# How to use jersey with Grizzly 2.3

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

I currently try out the Grizzly-Framework 2.3.6.
I am using the following maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-framework</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

I can start a server with the following code example:

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();
try {
    server.start();
    addJaxRS(server);
    System.out.println("Press any key to stop the server...");
    System.in.read();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

I added the following JAX-RS Class:

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    @GET 
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I tell grizzly to add the HelloWorldRessoruce as a JAX-RS Resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution by changing the dependency to "jersey-grizzly2" which includes the grizzly version 2.2.16

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I can now start grizzly with my JAX-RS resources like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyServerFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();
        // create jersey-grizzly server
        ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("my.resources");
        HttpServer server = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                "http://localhost:8080", rc);
        try {
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Press any key to stop the server...");
            System.in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But I initially thought that jersey is part of Grizzly?

Comment: Nope, Grizzly and Jersey are separate projects.

Comment: What sort of options are placed in "my.resources" ?

Comment: in my.resources I added my rest service classes with the jax-rs annotations. You can see the code here: https://github.com/rsoika/ImixsCrypt/tree/master/imixs-crypt-privacy/src/main/java/org/imixs/crypt

Comment: When you dont pass a boolean to createHttpServer() it will attempt to start the server after its created. You shouldnt need to call server.start().